# Implementing linear regression from scratch in python

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent, unsupervised-learning, calculus

I'm trying to Implement linear regression in python using the following gradient decent formulas (Notice that these formulas are after partial derive)
[slope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQcjo.png)
[y_intercept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhJsz.png)

but the code keeps giving me wearied results ,I think (I'm not sure) that the error is in the gradient_descent function

```
import numpy as np


class LinearRegression:
    def __init__(self , x:np.ndarray ,y:np.ndarray):
        self.x = x
        self.m = len(x)
        self.y = y


    def calculate_predictions(self ,slope:int , y_intercept:int) -> np.ndarray: # Calculate y hat.
        predictions = []

        for x in self.x:
            predictions.append(slope * x + y_intercept)

        return predictions

    def calculate_error_cost(self , y_hat:np.ndarray) -> int:
        error_valuse = []
        for i in range(self.m):
            error_valuse.append((y_hat[i] - self.y[i] )** 2)

        error = (1/(2*self.m)) * sum(error_valuse)
    
        return error
    

    def gradient_descent(self):
        costs = []

        # initialization values        
        temp_w = 0
        temp_b = 0
        
        a = 0.001 # Learning rate

        while True:
            y_hat = self.calculate_predictions(slope=temp_w , y_intercept= temp_b)
            
            sum_w = 0
            sum_b = 0

            for i in range(len(self.x)):
                sum_w += (y_hat[i] - self.y[i] ) * self.x[i]
                sum_b += (y_hat[i] - self.y[i] )

            w = temp_w - a * ((1/self.m) *sum_w)
            b = temp_b - a * ((1/self.m) *sum_b)
            temp_w = w
            temp_b = b


            costs.append(self.calculate_error_cost(y_hat))

            try:
                if costs[-1] > costs[-2]: # If global minimum reached
                    return [w,b]
            except IndexError:
                pass
```

I Used this dataset:-
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/tanuprabhu/linear-regression-dataset?resource=download

after downloading it like this:

```
import pandas

p = pandas.read_csv('linear_regression_dataset.csv') 

l = LinearRegression(x= p['X'] , y= p['Y'])
print(l.gradient_descent())
```

But It's giving me `[-568.1905905426412, -2.833321633515304]` Which is decently not accurate.

I want to implement the algorithm not using external modules like scikit-learn for learning purposes.

I tested the calculate_error_cost function and it worked as expected and I don't think that there is an error in the calculate_predictions function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One small problem you have is that you are returning the last values of w and b, when you should be returning the second-to-last parameters (because they yield a lower cost). This should not really matter that much... unless your learning rate is too high and you are immediately getting a higher value for the cost function on the second iteration. This I believe is your real problem, judging from the dataset you shared.

The algorithm does work on the dataset, but you need to **change the learning rate**. I ran it in the example below and it gave the result shown in the image. One caveat is that I added a limit to the iterations to avoid the algorithm from taking too long (and only marginally improving the result).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class LinearRegression:
    def __init__(self , x:np.ndarray ,y:np.ndarray):
        self.x = x
        self.m = len(x)
        self.y = y

    def calculate_predictions(self ,slope:int , y_intercept:int) -> np.ndarray: # Calculate y hat.
        predictions = []

        for x in self.x:
            predictions.append(slope * x + y_intercept)

        return predictions

    def calculate_error_cost(self , y_hat:np.ndarray) -> int:
        error_valuse = []
        for i in range(self.m):
            error_valuse.append((y_hat[i] - self.y[i] )** 2)

        error = (1/(2*self.m)) * sum(error_valuse)
    
        return error
    
    def gradient_descent(self):
        costs = []

        # initialization values        
        temp_w = 0
        temp_b = 0
        iteration = 0
        
        a = 0.00001 # Learning rate

        while iteration < 1000:
            y_hat = self.calculate_predictions(slope=temp_w , y_intercept= temp_b)
            
            sum_w = 0
            sum_b = 0

            for i in range(len(self.x)):
                sum_w += (y_hat[i] - self.y[i] ) * self.x[i]
                sum_b += (y_hat[i] - self.y[i] )

            w = temp_w - a * ((1/self.m) *sum_w)
            b = temp_b - a * ((1/self.m) *sum_b)

            costs.append(self.calculate_error_cost(y_hat))

            try:
                if costs[-1] > costs[-2]: # If global minimum reached
                    print(costs)
                    return [temp_w,temp_b]
            except IndexError:
                pass

            temp_w = w
            temp_b = b
            iteration += 1
            print(iteration)

        return [temp_w,temp_b]

p = pd.read_csv('linear_regression_dataset.csv')

x_data = p['X']
y_data = p['Y']
lin_reg = LinearRegression(x_data, y_data)
y_hat = lin_reg.calculate_predictions(*lin_reg.gradient_descent())

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x_data, y_data, 'r.', label='Data')
plt.plot(x_data, y_hat, 'b-', label='Linear Regression')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: Dataset and regression result]

Comment: I've edited the question and added the dataset that I used and the result that the code gives ,Please take a look.

Comment: @Kevin4678392 did you try playing with the learning rate?